# Handling extremely long timestep sequence in LSTM (NLP Multi-label classification)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow so sorry if I am not asking in a correct format. Let's say I am working with some extremely long timestep sequence datas (10000000), with 2701 samples and only one feature, my input array is `[2701,10000000,1]`,  and my dataset looks like

```
 [ 2.81143e-01  4.98219e-01 -8.08500e-03 ...  1.00000e+02  1.00000e+02
   1.00000e+02]
 [ 1.95077e-01  2.20920e-02 -1.68663e-01 ...  1.00000e+02  1.00000e+02
   1.00000e+02]
 ...
 [ 1.06033e-01  8.96650e-02 -3.20860e-01 ...  1.00000e+02  1.00000e+02
   1.00000e+02]
 [ 6.85510e-02 -3.83653e-01 -2.19265e-01 ...  1.00000e+02  1.00000e+02
   1.00000e+02]
 [ 2.51404e-01  8.02280e-02  2.84610e-01 ...  1.00000e+02  1.00000e+02
   1.00000e+02]]
```

However, from what I had read, usually LSTM network perform better in a range of (200~400) time steps, even ignoring the performance, I cannot successfully train with a single sample `[1,10000000,1]`. I believe the network is functional since I tried to limit the length of each sample to (1500), which is now `[2701,1500,1]` and it finally stop stucking at the first epoch. Here below is my code if needed:

```
from keras.utils import Sequence
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.format import open_memmap
import gc
import platform
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Masking
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC' #A "Best-fit with coalescing" algorithm, simplified from a version of dlmalloc.
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
set_session(tf.Session(config=config)) 

stock_price=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Final-Year-Project-master/stock_classification_7Days_test.csv",sep=',', dtype={"ID":"string","Class":int})
print(stock_price)


print (platform.architecture()) 

y_data=[]
x_data=[]

y_data=pd.get_dummies(stock_price['Class'])


def embedded_reader(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as embedded_raw:
        for line in embedded_raw:
            for word in line.split(','):
                try:
                    val=float(word)
                    yield val
                except:
                    pass
    
    embedded_raw.close()
    gc.collect()   
        

for y in range(len(stock_price)):
    if int(stock_price.at[y,'Class']) is not None:
        i = stock_price.at[y,'ID']
        print("Company code current: ",i)
        embedded_current=[]

        try:
            gen=embedded_reader("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Final-Year-Project-master/json_test/{}.jsonl".format(i))

            
            while True:
                val=next(gen)
                embedded_current.append(val)

        except:
            pass

                    
        fp=np.memmap('embedded_array.mymemmap', dtype=np.uint8,mode='w+',shape=(1,)) 
        fp=np.delete(fp,0)
        fp=np.concatenate((fp,embedded_current),axis=0)
        fp=np.pad(fp, (0,(10000000-len(embedded_current))), 'constant', constant_values=(100, 100))
        print(fp)
        x_data.append(fp)
        print(np.shape(x_data))
        del fp

        print("embedded_data current: ",len(embedded_current))

        print("this is number {}".format(y))
        print("-----------------------------")
        gc.collect()
        

    gc.collect()        


                  
print(len(x_data))
print(np.shape(x_data))
print("-"*20)
print(np.shape(y_data))
print(np.size(y_data))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data,y_data,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
print(np.shape(X_train))
print(np.shape(X_test))
X_train=np.array(X_train)
X_test=np.array(X_test)
print(np.shape(X_train))
print(np.shape(X_test))
print(X_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0],  X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],  X_train.shape[1], 1))
print(np.shape(X_train))
print(np.shape(X_test))
y_train=np.array(y_train)
y_test=np.array(y_test)

print(len(X_test[0]))
print(np.shape(y_train))


model=Sequential()

model.add(Masking(mask_value=100, input_shape=(10000000,1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=1, return_sequences = True, input_shape=(10000000,1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=1,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(5,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])


model.summary()
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=4,verbose=1)
print(model.predict(X_test))
print("class label:", reverse_label(model.predict_classes(X_test)))
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))



model.save('my_model')
```

From some tutorials they had mentioned to reshape the array, so I tried to reshape my array into something like `[2701*25000, 10000000/25000, 1]` but then I got stuck with the problem that x_data sample and y_data sample is not the same. Also I saw ones mentioned `model.fit_generator` but seems like it is solving the problem with huge sample size, which in my case, the model is not even working with a single sample (I am new to neural network so not sure if I am understanding it correctly). Totally got no clue and would really appreciate for any help, thank you.

Edit: just to state my question clear: "any advice on treating such long input using LSTM?"

Comment: Unsure if you seek advice on how to treat long input using LSTM or how to fix the length mismatch between x and y after reshaping. If you reshaped the inputs then you created 400*2701 new input samples. So x and y are not the same length. To alleviate this you should also "reshape" y, in this case replicating every y 400 times and making it all fit into a 2701*25000 vector.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I did have think about simply replicate the y_data to fit the shape, just not sure if it is a feasible way. So let's say if I am simply seeking advice on how to treat long input using LSTM , what will be my best bet? Or if reshaping the data is the popular way to go with this kind of problem? Once again, really appreciate for your time, it means a lot when I am googling for weeks and got almost nothing.

Comment: I have no knowledge in handling timestep sequences and very long input, I only use sequences of ~500 words. I don't think reshaping is a good method. Handling long dependencies was addressed with bidirectional encoders. Maybe you could try convolutionals neural networks? or try to use another tool ? If you do sequence labelling you could try simpler Conditional Random Fields (they were used a lot for text). Hope that helps

Comment: I ended up using both reshaping and fit_generator to handle the task, and it performs really bad just as expected, however for some reason I cannot change to another tool so I guess I will just accept it for now though it is quite...forcible. Anyway, still thanks for your time and I will make sure to check out those tools.